# Using a string variable as the condition of an if statement in php without using eval()

Tags: php, security, if-statement

My condition is generated by the code into a string to look like:

```
$mycondition = "(strpos(strtolower($foo1), strtolower($bar)) !== false) AND (strpos(strtolower($foo1),  strtolower($bar2)) !== false) // AND ((strpos(strtolower($foo2),  strtolower($bar1)) !== false)) AND..."; ad infinitum
```

My if statement should be like:

```
if ($mycondition) then...
```

I can do it with eval() like so:

```
if (eval("return $mycondition;")) then...
```

But I understand eval() is not recommended practice. On searching the forum, I see many voices calling against the use of eval(), but not really many alternatives.

What's the alternative? How do I just place the generated string into the if condition?

Comment: One workaround is that at the place where you are generating the condition, there only you can make the comparisons and generate a boolean at the end which you can later in the code.

Comment: Thank you @neeagl for opening my eyes to this - it solved my problem! I'm keeping a running comparison for each condition with a boolean variable which i end up checking in the if statement. Works like a charm. Thanks! No more evil eval()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is that at the place where you are generating the condition, there only you can make the comparisons and generate a boolean at the end which you can later in the code.